# altinity operator ClickHouse integration with LDAP

Tags: kubernetes, clickhouse

How to correctly write to the config?

Information taken from here
https://altinity.com/blog/integrating-clickhouse-with-ldap-part-one
Operator
https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator

```
Unknown setting server: while parsing profile 'ldap' in users configuration file: while loading configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml'
```

```
settings:
         # to allow scrape metrics via embedded prometheus protocol
         prometheus/endpoint: /metrics
         prometheus/port: 8888
         prometheus/metrics: true
         prometheus/events: true
         prometheus/asynchronous_metrics: true
         ldap_servers/ldap_test/host: host ldap
         ldap_servers/ldap_test/port: 389
         ldap_servers/ldap_test/bind_dn: DC=passport,DC=local
      profiles:
         ldap/server: ldap_test
```

Comment: Why do you put it under `profiles` ? It should be under `users`.

Comment: does not work everywhere. I can't seem to find a working configuration example

Comment: there are a lot of examples in CH sources /  tests

Comment: give me a link to at least one example, please

Comment: hope linsk from https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator/issues/1041, enough